# How is it possible that a command is found without, but not with sudo -E?

Tags: sudo

Afaik programs are found in `PATH` which is an environment variable and `sudo -E` executes a command with `root` permissions while preserving the environment of the invoking user (including `PATH`), thus any command `x` which is found by `which x` and can be executed as the current user should be found by `sudo -E which x` and be executable with `sudo -E x`.

For example, in the case of `jhbuild` (GNOME dependency resolution and build automation tool) which is installed into `$HOME/.local/bin` by default) this is not the case. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely your sudoers has the secure_path option set and it's overriding the PATH regardless of `-E`. You can either unset it or exempt specific users from it by adding them to `exempt_group`. See [sudoers(5)](http://man.developpez.com/man5/sudoers/) for more information.